# Split function going Abnormal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is the Contents of file from where i am reading...

```
aaa 3333,bbb 5,ccc 10
```

I am getting un defined for the keyvalue[2], [3], [4] and [5]. Why is it so???

I am actually first spliting based on , and then based on space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because you split by comma first, so item is now 'PrimeSuiteId 3333'. When you split that by space you get two items only, so 3rd value (keyvalue[2]) and above is empty.

---

Edit: possible fix to make second part of your script work

*swap*

```
var items = contents.toString().split(',');
```

*with*

```
var items = contents.toString().replace(/,/,' ');
```

which will simply replace commas with spaces in the original string so your array of expected values matches up

---

Another edit: because splitting by comma or space is better (as in comments)

```
var contents = f.read();
  Ti.API.info(contents);
  var items = contents.toString(); // changed to return complete string not split
  // removed for loop altogether
  var keyvalue = items.split(/,|\s/);  // changed to split by comma or space
  var AppointmentSearchDaysAfter = keyvalue[0];  
  var AppointmentSearchDaysAfterValue = keyvalue[1];
  var AppointmentSearchDaysBefore = keyvalue[2];  
  var AppointmentSearchDaysBeforeValue = keyvalue[3];
  var PrimeSuiteId = keyvalue[4];  
  var PrimeSuiteIdValue = keyvalue[5];
```

Comment: You either need to remove any references to keyvalue[n] where n>1 or you need to change the data to include more detail

Comment: i posted the same earlier than you and you get the correct answer :D

Comment: Better luck next time - I guess they like the completeness of my answer including comments from other users (you) - I voted for you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

From the contents in the contents file you should only be able to get values for

```
var AppointmentSearchDaysAfter = keyvalue[0];       
var AppointmentSearchDaysAfterValue = keyvalue[1];
```

You only have one space for each data entry between the commas

Answer (score 1):

Split function is working **fine**, you are expecting it to behave **abnormal**.

You will get only two values in array after split by space. From where will it bring 6 values!!!?

The rest values you will get in *next iterations*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring individual variables for each item and then loading them from the contents string, you can reduce the whole thing to an object with key/value pairs:

```
var items = contents.split(',').reduce(function (acc, val) {
    var split = val.split(' ');
    return acc[split[0]] = split[1], acc;
}, {});
```

To test what the values are, try:

```
console.log(items.PrimeSuiteId); // outputs 3333
console.log(items.AppointmentSearchDaysBefore); // outputs 5
console.log(items.AppointmentSearchDaysAfter); // outputs 10
```